# UIImageView does not recognize my tap events

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have an `UIImageView` that I have created like this:

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(test))

let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 150))
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Test")
imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
self.view.addSubview(imageView)
```

But for somehow is does not call the `test` function when I click on it... Seems like I have tried everything but it does not work. Any suggestions why?

Comment: You need to set `imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `UIImageView` is by default set to have the `isUserInteractionEnabled` property to `false`, that means that you can´t interact with the `UIImageView`.

Add this property and it will work:

```
imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Answer (score 1):

Add imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true